# Scraping specific tag and keyword, printing info associated with it using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape https://store.fabspy.com/collections/new-arrivals-beauty for the sapphire eye pencil product, and return the info associated with the product's id. So far I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = 'https://store.fabspy.com/collections/new-arrivals-beauty'
page = BeautifulSoup(url.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup((page))
tag = 'div class="product-content"'
if row in soup.html.body.findAll(tag):
    data = row.findAll('id')
    if data and 'sapphire' in data[0].text:
        print data[4].text
```

The information I am trying to receive is the following ;

```
<div class="product-content">
    <div class="pc-inner"> 
      <div data-handle="clematis-dewdrop-sparkling-eye-pencil-g7454c-sapphire" 
           data-target="#quick-shop-popup"
           class="quick_shop quick-shop-button"
           data-toggle="modal"
           title="Quick View">
        <span>+ Quick View</span>
        <span class="json hide">
          {
            "id":8779050374,
            "title":"Clematis - Dewdrop Sparkling Gel Eye Liner Pencil # G7454C**Sapphire**",
            "handle":"clematis-dewdrop-sparkling-eye-pencil-g7454c-sapphire",
            "description":"\u003cdiv\u003e\r\n\r\nGel Formula, Rich Colour, Matte Finish, Long-Wearing, Safe for Waterline\r\n\r\n\u003cbr\u003e\n\u003c\/div\u003e\u003cdiv\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003c\/div\u003e \u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"\/\/i.imgur.com\/adW5MKl.jpg\"\u003e",
            "published_at":"2016-10-17T20:15:40+08:00",
            "created_at":"2016-10-17T20:15:40+08:00",
            "vendor":"Clematis",
            "type":"Latest,Beauty,New,Makeup,Best, Clematis, Eyes",
            "tags":["Beauty","Best","Clematis","Eyes","Latest","Makeup","New"],
            "price":4900,
            "price_min":4900,
            "price_max":4900,
            "available":true,
            "price_varies":false,
            "compare_at_price":7900,
            "compare_at_price_min":7900,
            "compare_at_price_max":7900,
            "compare_at_price_varies":false,
            "variants":[{"id":31447937030", "title":"N\/A"]
          }
```

Specifically the `id` at the end. Please specify what tag my script should focus on to retrieve this info, and how I can keyword search for the `sapphire` color within the script and its `id`, thanks!

Comment: You need to focus on obtaining the text inside the `span` with `class="json hide"` and JSON parse the text

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in the existing code. I recommend using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) instead of `urllib2`. I'm also using the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) libraries. So this is what I would do in your case, (read the code for explanations).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json
# URL to scrape
url = 'https://store.fabspy.com/collections/new-arrivals-beauty'

# HTML data of the page
# You can add checks for 404 errors
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

# Get a list of all elements having `sapphire` in the `data-handle` attribute
sapphire = soup.findAll(attrs={'data-handle': re.compile(r".*sapphire.*")})
# Take first element of this list (I checked, there is just one element)
sapphire = sapphire[0]

# Find class inside this element having JSON data. Taking just first element's text
json_text = sapphire.findAll(attrs={'class': "json"})[0].text

# Converting it to a dictionary
data = json.loads(json_text)
print data["id"]
```

Comment: How can I scrape for the 'data-handle' element without knowing the amount of elements? Say when you set          sapphire = sapphire[0] assume I will never know how many of any element the page will have, same for the json_text line, thanks!

Comment: You can always check the length of the  `findAll()` function using the `len()` function. ( It's just a plain old list ). In this case, I printed the list and realised it has just one element

Comment: Instead of searching for the "id" attribute I will just search for the string because on this specific page I am scraping there is no ID attribute. Just going to use if (keyword) is in sapphire, print sapphire[0]. Nonetheless here is the code, getting index error: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json
import lxml
url = 'https://packershoes.com/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
sapphire = re.findall(r'<script type="text/javascript>"+.*</script>+', str(soup), re.I|re.M)
print(sapphire[0])
` nicer--> [link](http://pastebin.com/Wptc9B7r)

Comment: ^^didnt tag u before

Comment: Are you sure you have read and understood the code ive provided in the answer? Ive run the code on your page and it fetches the `id` you have asked for in the question. It doesn't look for any "id" attribute, it extracts it from JSON. If you want to get something else, please explicitly tell me. Your comment makes little sense

Comment: Yes, I thoroughly reviewed your code(which I appreciate you providing!) and it seems that your script (as indicated in comments too) searches for the keyword "sapphire" in all "data-handle" attributes. This doesnt work on [packershos.com](https://www.packershoes.com) as the "ID" information and the keyword I am searching for is all located under the 'script type="text/javascript>"' attribute. Above I posted my attempt at extracting that information using your script's blueprint. When I do attempt to use your intial script and change the keyword, I get: `
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I am truly trying to figure this out without bugging you but am  a bit stumped...

Comment: I think we should take this to chat

Comment: Could you join this? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129285/beautiful-soup-discussion

Comment: Not enough rep to join chats here, made one on this site [link](http://www.e-chat.co/room/175142) @martianwars